# Matlab ode functions to get specified number of values/outputs

Tags: matlab, ode

I have a function file with my differential equations, I am performing a ode23s on the function in the standard form i.e 
[t,m]=ode23s('DE_function',tspan,[mA pA mB pB mC pC mD],optionsDE,p)

I obtain about 150 values/results/output for each mA and so on. My ode23s is working fine. 
I have experimental dataset for the same mA and so on which i have to use to calculate the least squared error.. i am trying to do this:
a = m(:,1) - A(:,2); and so on. Here in my experimental data, I have just 20 values/results/outputs etc according to 20 time points. I have defined the same time points for the tspan as well. But since my matrices do not match in dimension, i am unable to proceed with my calculations. Is there a way to receive exactly 20 values according to the 20 time points such as 1, 2, etc in the ode23s as well, or may be a way to get and store them only.

I have been trying to find a solution for this error but unable to find anything suitable. Many thanks for any kind of suggestions and hits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Matlab documentation has all you need. When you call ode23 you can specify the time locations in tspan.

["Interval of integration, specified as a vector. At minimum, tspan must be a two element vector [t0 tf] specifying the initial and final times. To obtain solutions at specific times between t0 and tf, use a longer vector of the form [t0,t1,t2,...,tf]. The elements in tspan must be all increasing or all decreasing."](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ode23.html#inputarg_tspan)

Comment: Thank you so much, i had been looking for exactly something like this.